# How to safely make conversion from FT_HANDLE to a LPLONG - 64 bit compilation

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I am maintaining some code and after upgrading to a newer compiler, Visual Studio 2015, I am getting a compiler warning with the code below where a FT_HANDLE is converted to a LPLONG.

What is the safe way to do this conversion and to remove the warning?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef PVOID   FT_HANDLE;

void convert(FT_HANDLE ftHandle, LPLONG pPortNumber) {

    *pPortNumber = reinterpret_cast<long>(ftHandle) & 0xFF;  // problem here
}


int main() {

    FT_HANDLE handle = malloc(10);  // simulate a real handle
    LONG portNumber(0);
    convert(handle, &portNumber);
    std::cout << "result=" << &portNumber << '\n';
    free(handle);
}
```

compiler warnings:

```
warning C4311: 'reinterpret_cast': pointer truncation from 'FT_HANDLE' to 'long'
warning C4302: 'reinterpret_cast': truncation from 'FT_HANDLE' to 'long'
```

Comment: And that warning is... what, exactly?

Comment: How does the low 8 bits of an address correspond to anything?

Comment: What @1201ProgramAlarm means to say is that `FT_HANDLE` is a _pointer_. Presumably, you want to cast the value at that address, not the address itself. Try `reinterpret_cast<long>(*ftHandle)`.

Comment: If I try that I get error expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Comment: `FT_HANDLE` is a `void*`, so `*fthandle` is a `void`, which you can't cast.  As for the truncation warning, in a 64bit compilation, pointers are 64bit in size but `long` is 32bit in size. Use `LONG_PTR` instead of `long` in the `reinterpret_cast`.  Or change `FT_HANDLE` to `LONG_PTR` instead of `PVOID`. Either way, `&portNumber` should be `portNumber` in the `std::cout` statement

Comment: I've changed the question to disambiguate `pPortNumber` and `portNumber`. There used to be two `portNumber`s, buth with different types. This seemed directly related to the misunderstanding of how pointers work.

Answer (score 0):

The safe way is to *not* do this. The code appears unsalvageable.

The first part of problem is that `long` is 32 bits, and Win64 pointers aren't.

The second part is that `LPLONG portnumber` is passed by value. It's an input parameter, not an output parameter.

Comment: It is pretty bad agreed.  But LPLONG is a long* so dereferencing and assigning a value is at least a feasible thing to do.  So as passed as a pointer, caller will get updated ptr value.

Comment: @AngusComber: You seem to be have a problem with understanding pointers. Given `LPLONG pPortNumber`, you can assign a value to `pPortNumber` or you can assign a value to `*pPortNumber`. Assigning a value to `pPortNumber` does not change the value of either `&portNumber` or `portNumber`. The caller will **not** get a changed pointer that way.